# Efficiently calculate leap days

Tags: c, date, datetime, c99, leap-year

Im using the following function to calculate the number of leap days between two years:

```
static int CountLeapDays(int startYear, int endYear) 
{
    int Days = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        if ((startYear % 4 == 0 && startYear % 100 != 0) || startYear % 400 == 0)
            Days++;
        if (startYear + 1 == endYear) break;
        startYear++;
    }

    return Days;
}
```

Is there another way to write this so it doesnt need to loop?

Comment: Supposing the inputs are 2000 and 2012; there were 4 leap years in that period (2000, 2004, 2008, 2012).  Is that the answer you want?  It treats things as though the first date is 1st Jan [start] and the last 31st Dec [end], as a sweeping generality.  OTOH, between 1999 and 2011, there were only 3 leap years, even though there was a gap of 12 years, just the same.  And between 1997 and 2015, there were 4 leap years.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It should only count the leap days in between the two years, so first date is 31st Dec [start] and last date is 1st Jan [end]

Comment: OK...and so if the first year is the same as the last year, the answer is zero.  If the first year is after that last year, should that be an error, zero, or something else?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Correct! And it doesnt need to give an error, I handle input validation at a higher level.

Comment: `public static` in C???

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze `#define public /* nothing */`? :) — I noticed it while preparing my answer, but you commented first.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Oh, then how do we know if `int`, `while`, `true`, `break` and `return` are defined somehow? :)

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze You're right, I removed the 'public' statement. BTW: I wondered today how to optimize your 'SecondsSinceEpochToDateTime' function too, because it involves many large multiplications/divisions and my MCU has no support to do that in hardware.

Comment: Use a C99 compiler, it will support multiplication/division of 64-bit `long longs`. If you're stuck with C89, construct longer multiplications out of 4 shorter ones and implement long division just as you were taught at school. Research the topic. There's plenty helpful material online.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Im using C99 with GCC, but the problem is that the CPU (Cortex M0) cannot do hardware divisions, etc. So GCC will automaticly replace those operations with calls to library functions, which are much slower than letting a CPU handle the math. That's why I tried to modify your 'SecondsSinceEpochToDateTime' to only allow epochs past the year 2000, to reduce the total amount of integer arithmetic needed. But maybe im micro-optimizing too much ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can avoid all loops if you are careful with your analysis.

### CountLeapDays

#### Algorithm comments

```
/*
** Count the number of   4-year     leap years.
** Count the number of 100-year non-leap years.
** Count the number of 400-year     leap years.
**
** Switchover between 20th and 21st centuries: 2000 was a leap year.
** Early        Later year
**       1996 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009
** 1996    0     0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    2    2    2    2    3
** 1997    -     0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    2    2    2    2    3
** 1998    -     -    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    2    2    2    2    3
** 1999    -     -    -    0    0    1    1    1    1    2    2    2    2    3
** 2000    -     -    -    -    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    2
** 2001    -     -    -    -    -    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    2
** 2002    -     -    -    -    -    -    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    2
** 2003    -     -    -    -    -    -    -    0    0    1    1    1    1    2
** 2004    -     -    -    -    -    -    -    -    0    0    0    0    0    1
** 2005    -     -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    0    0    0    0    1
** 2006    -     -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    0    0    0    1
** 2007    -     -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    0    0    1
** 2008    -     -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    0    0
**
** Switchover between 19th and 20th centuries: 1900 was not a leap year.
** Early        Later year
**       1896 1897 1898 1899 1900 1901 1902 1903 1904 1905 1906 1907 1908 1909
** 1896    0     0    0    0    0   *0   *0   *0   *0   *1   *1   *1   *1   *2
** 1897    -     0    0    0    0   *0   *0   *0   *0   *1   *1   *1   *1   *2
** 1898    -     -    0    0    0   *0   *0   *0   *0   *1   *1   *1   *1   *2
** 1899    -     -    -    0    0   *0   *0   *0   *0   *1   *1   *1   *1   *2
** 1900    -     -    -    -    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    2
** 1901    -     -    -    -    -    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    2
** 1902    -     -    -    -    -    -    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    2
** 1903    -     -    -    -    -    -    -    0    0    1    1    1    1    2
** 1904    -     -    -    -    -    -    -    -    0    0    0    0    0    1
** 1905    -     -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    0    0    0    0    1
** 1906    -     -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    0    0    0    1
** 1907    -     -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    0    0    1
** 1908    -     -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    0    0
**
** The dashes can be returned as zero as a special case (invalid input).
** The leading diagonal (zeros) are a special case.
**
** The starred values are 'exceptional', because the (end year - 1) is
** in a different century from the start year.
** Note that the corresponding positions in the other table are doubly
** exceptional because they could be calculated as (end year - 1) is in
** a different century from the start year (one smaller) and (end year -
** 1) is in a different quad-century (one larger) for a net change of
** zero.  This matters if the date ranges get bigger (1890..2130, for
** example).
*/

#include <assert.h>

extern int CountLeapDays(int lo, int hi);   // Should be in a header
```

#### CountLeapDays function

```
int CountLeapDays(int lo, int hi)
{
    assert(lo >= 1800);
    assert(hi <= 9999);
    assert(lo <= hi);

    /* Covers wild inputs */
    /* Beware: 1600 was not a leap year under the Julian calendar then in effect */
    if (lo > hi || lo < 1800 || hi > 9999)
        return 0;

    /* Leading diagonal */
    if (lo == hi)
        return 0;

    /* Regular leap years */
    int lo_4 = (lo - 0) / 4;    /* 500 */
    int hi_4 = (hi - 1) / 4;    /* 502 */
    int diff = hi_4 - lo_4;     /*   2 */

    /* Century years are not leap years */
    int lo_c = (lo - 0) / 100;
    int hi_c = (hi - 1) / 100;
    diff -= hi_c - lo_c;

    /* Quad-century years are leap years */
    int lo_q = (lo - 0) / 400;
    int hi_q = (hi - 1) / 400;
    diff += hi_q - lo_q;

    return(diff);
}
```

You can decide whether it is a worthwhile optimization to test for `hi_c != lo_c` and only do the subtraction and quad-century calculation if that's true.  The calculation as written is neatly symmetric (and the `- 0` terms are there for the symmetry too; the compiler will discard the subtraction).

### Test code

#### Test data

The test data was generated from the tables in the comments by a Perl script.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static struct test
{
    int lo;
    int hi;
    int num;
} tests[] =
{
    { 1996, 1996, 0 },
    { 1996, 1997, 0 },
    { 1996, 1998, 0 },
    { 1996, 1999, 0 },
    { 1996, 2000, 0 },
    { 1996, 2001, 1 },
    { 1996, 2002, 1 },
    { 1996, 2003, 1 },
    { 1996, 2004, 1 },
    { 1996, 2005, 2 },
    { 1996, 2006, 2 },
    { 1996, 2007, 2 },
    { 1996, 2008, 2 },
    { 1996, 2009, 3 },
    { 1997, 1997, 0 },
    { 1997, 1998, 0 },
    { 1997, 1999, 0 },
    { 1997, 2000, 0 },
    { 1997, 2001, 1 },
    { 1997, 2002, 1 },
    { 1997, 2003, 1 },
    { 1997, 2004, 1 },
    { 1997, 2005, 2 },
    { 1997, 2006, 2 },
    { 1997, 2007, 2 },
    { 1997, 2008, 2 },
    { 1997, 2009, 3 },
    { 1998, 1998, 0 },
    { 1998, 1999, 0 },
    { 1998, 2000, 0 },
    { 1998, 2001, 1 },
    { 1998, 2002, 1 },
    { 1998, 2003, 1 },
    { 1998, 2004, 1 },
    { 1998, 2005, 2 },
    { 1998, 2006, 2 },
    { 1998, 2007, 2 },
    { 1998, 2008, 2 },
    { 1998, 2009, 3 },
    { 1999, 1999, 0 },
    { 1999, 2000, 0 },
    { 1999, 2001, 1 },
    { 1999, 2002, 1 },
    { 1999, 2003, 1 },
    { 1999, 2004, 1 },
    { 1999, 2005, 2 },
    { 1999, 2006, 2 },
    { 1999, 2007, 2 },
    { 1999, 2008, 2 },
    { 1999, 2009, 3 },
    { 2000, 2000, 0 },
    { 2000, 2001, 0 },
    { 2000, 2002, 0 },
    { 2000, 2003, 0 },
    { 2000, 2004, 0 },
    { 2000, 2005, 1 },
    { 2000, 2006, 1 },
    { 2000, 2007, 1 },
    { 2000, 2008, 1 },
    { 2000, 2009, 2 },
    { 2001, 2001, 0 },
    { 2001, 2002, 0 },
    { 2001, 2003, 0 },
    { 2001, 2004, 0 },
    { 2001, 2005, 1 },
    { 2001, 2006, 1 },
    { 2001, 2007, 1 },
    { 2001, 2008, 1 },
    { 2001, 2009, 2 },
    { 2002, 2002, 0 },
    { 2002, 2003, 0 },
    { 2002, 2004, 0 },
    { 2002, 2005, 1 },
    { 2002, 2006, 1 },
    { 2002, 2007, 1 },
    { 2002, 2008, 1 },
    { 2002, 2009, 2 },
    { 2003, 2003, 0 },
    { 2003, 2004, 0 },
    { 2003, 2005, 1 },
    { 2003, 2006, 1 },
    { 2003, 2007, 1 },
    { 2003, 2008, 1 },
    { 2003, 2009, 2 },
    { 2004, 2004, 0 },
    { 2004, 2005, 0 },
    { 2004, 2006, 0 },
    { 2004, 2007, 0 },
    { 2004, 2008, 0 },
    { 2004, 2009, 1 },
    { 2005, 2005, 0 },
    { 2005, 2006, 0 },
    { 2005, 2007, 0 },
    { 2005, 2008, 0 },
    { 2005, 2009, 1 },
    { 2006, 2006, 0 },
    { 2006, 2007, 0 },
    { 2006, 2008, 0 },
    { 2006, 2009, 1 },
    { 2007, 2007, 0 },
    { 2007, 2008, 0 },
    { 2007, 2009, 1 },
    { 2008, 2008, 0 },
    { 2008, 2009, 0 },
    { 1896, 1896, 0 },
    { 1896, 1897, 0 },
    { 1896, 1898, 0 },
    { 1896, 1899, 0 },
    { 1896, 1900, 0 },
    { 1896, 1901, 0 },
    { 1896, 1902, 0 },
    { 1896, 1903, 0 },
    { 1896, 1904, 0 },
    { 1896, 1905, 1 },
    { 1896, 1906, 1 },
    { 1896, 1907, 1 },
    { 1896, 1908, 1 },
    { 1896, 1909, 2 },
    { 1897, 1897, 0 },
    { 1897, 1898, 0 },
    { 1897, 1899, 0 },
    { 1897, 1900, 0 },
    { 1897, 1901, 0 },
    { 1897, 1902, 0 },
    { 1897, 1903, 0 },
    { 1897, 1904, 0 },
    { 1897, 1905, 1 },
    { 1897, 1906, 1 },
    { 1897, 1907, 1 },
    { 1897, 1908, 1 },
    { 1897, 1909, 2 },
    { 1898, 1898, 0 },
    { 1898, 1899, 0 },
    { 1898, 1900, 0 },
    { 1898, 1901, 0 },
    { 1898, 1902, 0 },
    { 1898, 1903, 0 },
    { 1898, 1904, 0 },
    { 1898, 1905, 1 },
    { 1898, 1906, 1 },
    { 1898, 1907, 1 },
    { 1898, 1908, 1 },
    { 1898, 1909, 2 },
    { 1899, 1899, 0 },
    { 1899, 1900, 0 },
    { 1899, 1901, 0 },
    { 1899, 1902, 0 },
    { 1899, 1903, 0 },
    { 1899, 1904, 0 },
    { 1899, 1905, 1 },
    { 1899, 1906, 1 },
    { 1899, 1907, 1 },
    { 1899, 1908, 1 },
    { 1899, 1909, 2 },
    { 1900, 1900, 0 },
    { 1900, 1901, 0 },
    { 1900, 1902, 0 },
    { 1900, 1903, 0 },
    { 1900, 1904, 0 },
    { 1900, 1905, 1 },
    { 1900, 1906, 1 },
    { 1900, 1907, 1 },
    { 1900, 1908, 1 },
    { 1900, 1909, 2 },
    { 1901, 1901, 0 },
    { 1901, 1902, 0 },
    { 1901, 1903, 0 },
    { 1901, 1904, 0 },
    { 1901, 1905, 1 },
    { 1901, 1906, 1 },
    { 1901, 1907, 1 },
    { 1901, 1908, 1 },
    { 1901, 1909, 2 },
    { 1902, 1902, 0 },
    { 1902, 1903, 0 },
    { 1902, 1904, 0 },
    { 1902, 1905, 1 },
    { 1902, 1906, 1 },
    { 1902, 1907, 1 },
    { 1902, 1908, 1 },
    { 1902, 1909, 2 },
    { 1903, 1903, 0 },
    { 1903, 1904, 0 },
    { 1903, 1905, 1 },
    { 1903, 1906, 1 },
    { 1903, 1907, 1 },
    { 1903, 1908, 1 },
    { 1903, 1909, 2 },
    { 1904, 1904, 0 },
    { 1904, 1905, 0 },
    { 1904, 1906, 0 },
    { 1904, 1907, 0 },
    { 1904, 1908, 0 },
    { 1904, 1909, 1 },
    { 1905, 1905, 0 },
    { 1905, 1906, 0 },
    { 1905, 1907, 0 },
    { 1905, 1908, 0 },
    { 1905, 1909, 1 },
    { 1906, 1906, 0 },
    { 1906, 1907, 0 },
    { 1906, 1908, 0 },
    { 1906, 1909, 1 },
    { 1907, 1907, 0 },
    { 1907, 1908, 0 },
    { 1907, 1909, 1 },
    { 1908, 1908, 0 },
    { 1908, 1909, 0 },
};
enum { NUM_TESTS = sizeof(tests) / sizeof(tests[0]) };
```

#### Test functions

```
static void test_data(void)
{
    int pass = 0;
    int fail = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TESTS; i++)
    {
        int res = CountLeapDays(tests[i].lo, tests[i].hi);
        if (res != tests[i].num)
        {
            printf("!! FAIL !! %4d..%4d wanted %d actual %d\n", tests[i].lo, tests[i].hi, tests[i].num, res);
            fail++;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("== PASS == %4d..%4d = %d\n", tests[i].lo, tests[i].hi, tests[i].num);
            pass++;
        }
    }
    if (fail == 0)
        printf("== PASS == %d tests passed\n", pass);
    else
        printf("!! FAIL !! %d tests out of %d failed\n", fail, pass+fail);
}

static void test_range(int min, int max)
{
    for (int lo = min; lo < max; lo++)
    {
        for (int hi = lo; hi < max; hi++)
        {
            printf("%d..%d = %d leap days\n", lo, hi, CountLeapDays(lo, hi));
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    test_data();
    test_range(1997, 2016);
    test_range(1891, 1909);
    return(0);
}
```

The test code passes the 208 test cases that are formally verified from the data.  It goes on to illustrate 361 cases spanning both the 19th-20th and 20th-21st century time spans.

Comment: Wow! Almost unbelievable how much time and effort you spended just to answer this question! Thank you very much!

Comment: The tables were key to working out what was necessary. Hacking them with Perl was pretty easy. The test code is in a standard scheme I use for unit-testing similar calculations (including date calculations) — inputs and expected output; compare and complain. I had those tests in place before I had a working algorithm; they were key to getting it to work. The main itself is trivial. That really only leaves the algorithm, but even that fell into place fairly quickly once I'd got the tables with the inputs and required outputs. But yes, it was quite a lot of work...despite my minimizing it.

Comment: @Joshua: FYI: my code doesn't produce exactly the same answer as your code.  Even after upgrading it to handle start year the same as end year (`if (startYear >= endYear) return 0;`), the answers are different.  Your code counts the leap day in the start year (using 1st January [Start]).

Answer (score 3):

There are probably much faster alternatives but this version at least reduces the number of loops by ~75%

```
public static int CountLeapDays(int startYear, int endYear) 
{
    int Days = 0;

    // round startYear up to the nearest multiple of 4
    startYear += 3;
    startYear &= ~3;

    while (startYear <= endYear) {
        if (startYear % 100 != 0 || startYear % 400 == 0) {
            Days++;
        }
        startYear += 4;
    }

    return Days;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could loop a lot less by:

1. There are 97 leap days in every 400 years. This can be calculated without looping.
2. Divide the number of years in the remaining range by 4 and add it to the number from step 1 for an approximate answer.
3. Subtract one for any years within the range that are multiples of 100 and not multiples of 400. You can start your loop from (startyear+99)/100*100 and increment by 100 until your value is > endYear. This will only loop a maximum of three times.

Comment: Theoretically, yes. However, the year 1600 wasn't a leap year in most countries, and we don't know if 2400 will ever happen. :-)

Comment: @BoPersson 1600 was most definitely a leap year in all countries. The problem is, rather, that 1700 was in some of them. I was kind of assuming proleptic gregorian calendar, since that's what the code in the question is doing.

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase this: In the year 1600 most countries didn't follow the current rules, in the year 2000 they did, but we know nothing at all about the year 2400. That makes it hard to give a rule about any 400 year period.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible without a loop.

```
static int CountLeapDays(int start, int end)
{
    int years = end - start
    int days = 0

    days += years / 4 + 1
    days -= years / 100 + 1
    days += years / 400 + 1

    if (start - start % 4 + 4 > end)
        days -= 1;

    if (start - start % 100 + 100 > end)
        days -= 1;

    if (start - start % 400 + 400 > end)
        days -= 1;

    return days
}
```

Basic explanation:

1. Calculate leap days by totalYears / 4
2. Remove all divisible by 100
3. Add back all divisible by 400

For simplicity, the algorithm assumes there is at least 1 match for each situation. If there isn't, then it removes it. For example, 1997 to 1999 does not include any leap years so the following is true (start - start % 4 + 4 > end) thus need 1 removed from the total.

OR

For people who like really short code (i is start year, and j is end year).

```
(j-i)/4-(i-i%4+4>j?-1:0)-(j-i)/100-(i-i%100+100>j?-1:0)+(j-i)/400-(i-i%400+400>j?-1:0)+1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get why that takes too much effort to come into only with this:

```
inline size_t get_leap_days(size_t year)
{
    ASSERT_GE(year, 1800);
    const size_t prev_year = year - 1;
    return prev_year / 4 - prev_year / 100 + prev_year / 400;
}

inline void test_get_leap_days(size_t begin_year, size_t end_year, size_t eta_leap_days)
{
    const double leap_days = begin_year < end_year ? get_leap_days(end_year) - get_leap_days(begin_year + 1) : 0;
    ASSERT_EQ(leap_days, eta_leap_days);
}
```